# JHipster - generate fake data

Tags: java, spring-boot, jhipster, faker

I'm using jHipster generator for my project in Java. On front-end is AngularJS and on back-end is Spring Boot.

To populate data in my database I'm using Liquibase and its CSV files.

Now, my question is, is there a way to use some Faker classes to populate big amount of data in my DB and how can I run it? Now I'm doing it manually through CSV files but it's really painfull and slow.

Does anyone knows anything about this?

Thank you.

Comment: what means bit amount? 100, 1000, 10.000, more?

Comment: about 10 000 rows or more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [DbSetup](http://dbsetup.ninja-squad.com/), it's very flexible as you generate your data in java and is quite fast. Combine it with [JFairy](https://codearte.github.io/jfairy/)